# I'm available for 7 o'clock - is it correct?

Tags: prepositions, usage

Someone ask for my availability, can I say I'm available **for** certain time?

> I'm available for 7 o'clock

Answer (score 1):

Greetings and welcome to ELL StackExchange :)

When I say

> I am available for X

X is the thing which I am available for, not the time at which I am available. One word you could use instead is "**at"**:

> I am available for X **at** 7 o'clock

You could even be more specific about the conditions of your availability as they relate to time:

> I am available for X **starting/beginning at** 7 o'clock

or

> I am available for X **until/up to** 7 o'clock

Can you provide some context? In what situation(s) are you stating your availability?

Comment: I work as a lorry driver and the person ask me if I'm up for a shift. In that case is the proposition for correct as in I'm available for 7 o'clock? Meaning I can come in at 7 clock

Comment: And I mean to say that I can only come at 7. Thx

Answer (score 0):

"For" may work if there is an appointment or something similar at 7, but then you would say it as "I'm available for *the* 7 o'clock." "I'm available for the 7 o'clock" may work for a shift. Otherwise, you would say (because you have said this means "can only come at") "I'm [only] available at 7 o'clock."

Comment: What about if there is no mention of any previous appointments and I'm self employed and want to express my desire that it is me that decides what shift I want to do. I'm the boss kind of attitude. Would I'm available for 7 o'clock or I will be available for 7 o'clock work? I know that you mentioned that I need to add the but it sound like it's a set appointment or sth.